# Can I force onEvent to interact with data provided by filter function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please refer to the below code, written by the user @doubleunary
The purpose of the code is to remove the content of the rows in which the matching column had its contents removed manually by the user. However, I realized that in this instance. I want to remove the content from Sheet 2, which uses a filter to populate data from sheet 1. The script does not recognize changes done in sheet 1, as modifications to data in sheet 2, and does not function. Is there any way to adjust that?

```
 function onEdit(e) {
      if (e.range.columnStart !== 1
        || e.range.rowStart <= 1
        || e.range.getSheet().getName() !== 'Sheet2'
        || (e.value || e.range.getValue())
        || e.range.getHeight() + e.range.getWidth() > 2) {
        return;
      }
      e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 5).clearContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Respond to changes in multiple sheets

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1 + e.range.columnEnd - e.range.columnStart + 1 < 2 && e.value === '' && e.oldValue) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 5).clearContent();
  }
}
```